# How atom works and it's different from DNA?

Tags: dna, human-anatomy

I am studying atoms recently because I am writing a short story and the characters would talk about it for a bit. And I wish it's scientifically accurate.

So I read a lot of articles about the atom and here is something that I saw:

> Around three-quarters of a human body is water, made from oxygen and
>   hydrogen atoms. These atoms, along with all the others in the world,
>   have been around for eons, shifting through any number of organic and
>   inorganic processes, or simply hanging about in the atmosphere.
>   Anybody could have some oxygen or hydrogen atoms in their constitution
>   that had once been part of Einstein, Elvis Presley or Mother Teresa.
>   On the other hand, an atom could have once been part of a decomposing
>   piece of rat offal.

So, if I really got some atoms of Einstein, it doesn't work like DNA which I might have curly hair right?

Thanks!

Comment: If you recycle plastic or metal then does it mean that it will retain the properties of the the object that it had been in the past? Think about it. I don't want to be dismissive but your question is super elementary! You **must** do some reading on your part before asking others.

Comment: you should probably read what is DNA, this should clear things up

Answer (score 2):

DNA is a complex molecule which contains the genetic information. DNA, just like any other molecule, is made of atoms. However, the atoms themselves do not contain any genetic information.

To be more accurate, DNA is made of a double strand (themselves made of atoms) and among those two strands are a succession of elements that we call nucleotides. The 4 four possible nucleotides; Adenine, Thymine, Cytosine and Guanine (usually, just called, A,T,C and G). Nucleotides are simple(-ish) molecules. The genetic information is in the succession of four nucleotides. For an analogy, consider the nucleotides to be letters and the succession of letters make words and sentences. The letters themselves don't hold information but their succession does. For example, the letter "**r**" in itself does not have much meaning but it is essential for the sentence "The doo**r** is **r**ed" to make sense.

So, whether one of the atom found in a given nucleotide (or anywhere else) has been in Einstein's body or not, does not change anything in your genetic information.